# Div titles/headers

Tags: html, css

I want to make it so the two h1 elements are titles/headers on the div. So each one is on top of the specific div.

```
    <div class="test">
        <h1 style="color: white; margin:0 auto;">Youtube</h1>
        <h1 style="color: white; margin:0 auto;">Achievements</h1>
        <div class="BoxHolder" style="width: 420px; height: 345px; float: left; padding: 15px 10px; display: block;">
            <embed width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        </div>
        <div class="BoxHolder" style="width: 420px; height: 345px; float: right; padding: 15px 10px; display: block;">
            <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
            <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
            <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
            <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
            <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
            <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
            <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
            <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
            <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
            <div class="achievements"><hr></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
    .main {
        width:auto;
        height:262px;
        margin-bottom:50px
    }
    .boxholder{
        margin:0 auto;
        height:300px;
        width:935px;
        border:1px solid #2F2F2F;
        box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 15px #181818
    }
    .test{
        width:902px;
        margin: 0 auto 50px;
    }
    .mascotlinks img {
         height:100%;
         width:33%;
         position:left;
     }
    .achievements {
        height:7%;
    }
```

Also please be sure to give me some pointers on where to improve this code and also anything else. Im new to this. Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure for SEO purposes, you're only supposed to have one h1 element per page. A little off-topic, sorry.

Comment: If you want each one to be a title for a specific DIV, it should be put right before that DIV, not all together at the top of everything.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for replying, we are getting somewhere but why is one lower then the other now - http://imgur.com/Jj68PDu

Comment: The second `h1` is now after the YouTube video, so why would you expect it to line up with the first `h1`, which is before it? What you should probably do is wrap another DIV around the combined header and contents, and then lay those out inline with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are looking for but I made a jsfiddle so you can take a look.
http://jsfiddle.net/kriscoulson/ocekg2oc/

All you need to do is take the h1's and put them underneath the .BoxHolder class.

```
    <div class="BoxHolder" style="width: 420px; height: 345px; float: left; padding: 15px 10px; display: block;">
        <h1>Youtube</h1>
        <embed width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    </div>
    <div class="BoxHolder" style="width: 420px; height: 345px; float: right; padding: 15px 10px; display: block;">
        <h1>Achievements</h1>
        <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
        <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
        <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
        <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
        <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
        <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
        <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
        <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
        <div class="achievements"><hr></div>
        <div class="achievements"><hr></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Also you should try to lay off the inline styles you could do all of that in css and keep you code alot cleaner. And the H1 tags should only be used for headings such as when you come to the homepage. Try using h2 tags and style them with css

```
h2 {
font-size:42px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build 2 box floating, one left one right and then clear both. Each box would have the title inside and the code. Here is an example:

HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box-yt">
         <h1>Youtube</h1>

        <embed width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    </div>
    <div class="box box-achiev">
         <h1>Achievement</h1>

        <div class="content-achiev">
            <ul>
                <li>Achievement NO.1</li>
                <li>Achievement NO.2</li>
                <li>Achievement NO.3</li>
                <li>Achievement NO.4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper .box-yt {
    float: left;
}
.wrapper .box-achiev {
    float: right;
}
.wrapper .box h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.wrapper .clear {
    clear: both;
}
.content-achiev ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 220px;
}
.content-achiev li {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Also if you don't want to put inside achievements anything else but some text and a link use a list, like i did.